# what is utempter, and why does xterm want to use it?

Tags: xterm, setuid

when I start `xterm`, it tries to start a binary:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/utempter/utempter
```

I could not find any info as to what this binary is for.

`man utempter` has no entry, and searching the web for "utempter" only brings up links with possible vulnerabilities. This binary has the `s` bit set.

Why does xterm want to start i?
What is the purpose of this binary?
can I tell xterm not to start it ?

Comment: Here you find a brief description: https://packages.debian.org/buster/libutempter0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`utempter` is a setgid helper which `xterm` uses to update [`utmp`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/utmp.5.html). It exists so that `xterm` itself doesn’t need to be privileged enough to touch `utmp`. On Debian at least it is also used by `screen`, `tmux`, `mosh` and a few other terminal emulators.

You can instruct `xterm` not to try to use it by starting it with `-ut`, which disables writing records in the `utmp` file.