# urxvt starts two processes

Tags: rxvt

I've started using `urxvt` and noticed that it starts 2 PIDs each time opened. They are consecutive. I do not include `bash`.

`ps`

```
PID    %CPU %MEM   VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
21193  0.1  0.3 113368 29340 ?        Ss   12:13   0:00 rxvt
21194  0.0  0.0  31932  3716 ?        S    12:13   0:00 rxvt
```

`pstree`

```
├─rxvt─┬─bash
       └─rxvt
```

I tried `urxvtd` (the rxvt daemon), it also starts 2 PIDs. I haven't seen this behaviour on `st` or `xterm`. They open for themselves one process and `bash`. Is it normal?

Debian 10, rxvt-unicode package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`urxvt`** runs setuid/setgid to work with *`utmp/wtmp`* (the feature which lets you use the [`who`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/who.1.html) and [`last`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/last.1.html) commands).  Doing this directly is considered a potential vulnerability.  **`xterm`** generally uses [utempter](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/605269/what-is-utempter-and-why-does-xterm-want-to-use-it), to guard against that.  **`st`** has no direct support for *`utmp/wtmp`*.  According to its FAQ, you can make that work using another program:

```
## Why does st not handle utmp entries?

Use the excellent tool of [utmp](https://git.suckless.org/utmp/) for this task
```

urxvt's documentation explains the fork in a different manner:

> **[I need to make it setuid/setgid to support utmp/ptys on my OS, is this safe?](https://github.com/exg/rxvt-unicode/blob/ed141d36d44af3ea9a70c8386780938bfba891d6/README.FAQ#L1030)**

> It should be, starting with release 7.1. You are encouraged to properly
> install urxvt with privileges necessary for your OS now.

> When rxvt-unicode detects that it runs setuid or setgid, it will fork
> into a helper process for privileged operations (pty handling on some
> systems, utmp/wtmp/lastlog handling on others) and drop privileges
> immediately. This is much safer than most other terminals that keep
> privileges while running (but is more relevant to urxvt, as it contains
> things as perl interpreters, which might be "helpful" to attackers).

> This forking is done as the very first within main(), which is very
> early and reduces possible bugs to initialisation code run before
> main(), or things like the dynamic loader of your system, which should
> result in very little risk.

One easy way to see if a terminal supports utmp/wtmp is to run the **`w`** command.  The resulting output will show that **`w`** command if the terminal supports the feature.  I see this in **`xterm`**:

```
 09:57:14 up  2:34,  5 users,  load average: 0.05, 0.01, 0.00
USER     TTY      FROM             LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
tom      pts/1    192.168.1.8:S.0  07:24    5:45   7.49s  7.46s vile
tom      pts/2    192.168.1.8:S.1  07:25   42:02   0.13s  0.10s ded /usr/build/
tom      pts/3    192.168.1.8:S.2  09:15    7:45   0.41s  0.38s ded rpmbuild//S
tom      pts/4    192.168.1.8:S.3  09:51   12.00s  0.16s  0.00s sh -c uxterm-de
tom      pts/5    localhost:10.0   09:57    0.00s  0.04s  0.00s w
```

and this in **`st`**:

```
 09:59:07 up  2:36,  4 users,  load average: 0.00, 0.00, 0.00
USER     TTY      FROM             LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
tom      pts/1    192.168.1.8:S.0  07:24    7:38   7.58s  7.55s vile
tom      pts/2    192.168.1.8:S.1  07:25   43:55   0.13s  0.10s ded /usr/build/
tom      pts/3    192.168.1.8:S.2  09:15    9:38   0.41s  0.38s ded rpmbuild//SOURCES/
tom      pts/4    192.168.1.8:S.3  09:51   27.00s  0.39s  0.00s sh -c stterm
```

Comment: Interesting. Yet `st` returns result from `who` and `last` commands, same as when executed from `urxvt`.

Comment: `who` and `last` will return output, but checking here, running `w` (which would show the command being run in particular) shows nothing relevant for `st`: its source mentions a helper program which can be run.